# Post facebook ad using facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to post facebook ads using the developers API.

Currently I am using the [Power editor](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor/) to enter the ad details and entering the details of the ad like so.

[image: Power Editor]

I would like to automate the above process somewhat with the API.

Currently I have been able to `POST` to my page as my page using the graph api explorer (by posting to `/<MY PAGE>/links`). I am looking for a similar such way to post ads, ideally a demo from the API explorer would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/overview/

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, do you know if I should be able to experiment with ads API in the graph API explorer (provided I grant `manage_ads` and related permissions)? I seem to be getting some auth errors with graph API explorer

Comment: No, you need to apply for and be approved for access to the ads api in order to use it - the first line of the document CBRoe linked explains this